# Update Param with constraint

Tags: pyomo

i want to define a constraint, which update param when assignment is occur. The constraint is as [follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR5V2.png).

Where d is Param and Z is decision variable define as:

```
model.d = Param(model.V, mutable=True)
model.Z = Var(model.Vs, model.Vc2, within = Binary)
```

I have tried:

```
def Cons24_rule(model,i):
    return model.d[i] == sum(model.d[j] * model.Z[i,j] for j in model.Vc2)
model.Cons24 = Constraint(model.Vs , rule = Cons24_rule)
```

but i get infeasibility error. How Can i able to define this constraint?

Pyomo code and test data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YJYoqlSSaL7sbPzr1gqdA-iqa5nUsHCS?usp=sharing).

Thanks - Soheil

Comment: What do you mean "which update param when assignment is occur"? You cannot update a parameter; a parameter is a fixed value.

Comment: i model 2E-VRP. In this model there is one depot and set of intermediate facilities, demand for each facilities is unknown, and after customer assignment (Z[i,j]) it demand should be calculated (d[j]).

Comment: In that case you are not "assigning a value" to the parameter or "updating" the parameter; you are just writing a constraint that forces a sum to equal that parameter. I would suggest that you edit the title and question accordingly. More importantly, you should include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise we cannot run your code and test it. It's possible you just have a pyomo error, but I suspect that your instance is, in fact, infeasible, so pyomo is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here on SO, you might try closing the question here and asking on the new [or.se] SE instead.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, if i define an initialize value for d and disable that constraint, i don't get infeasibility error. i have also add Pyomo code.

Comment: If `d` is a parameter, not a decision variable, then I'm not sure what you mean by "initial value" -- a parameter only has one value, and can't be changed. It's not surprising that you don't get an infeasibility message if you disable that constraint, but that still doesn't indicate whether you have an infeasible instance (I suspect so) or a pyomo bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your instance is infeasible. Your constraint says:

```
d[i] = sum {j in V_c2} d[j] * Z[i,j]
```

for all `i`. This means the amount shipped out of `i` must exactly equal its `d`, and the amount shipped must fully equal the `d` of the destinations. But for example, `d[9] = 6`, and there are no other nodes `j` such that `sum {j} d[j] = 6`. So, there is no way to satisfy this constraint, i.e., no way to ship exactly 6 units out of node `9`.

I suspect that the real problem is in the logic of your constraint formulation, not in your data. I don't think you want to assume that if `i` ships to `j`, then it must ship *all* of `d[j]`. Either that, or you don't want to require the total shipped out of `i` to equal `d[i]` *exactly*.

Comment: Not for all i, only for i in model.Vs, i.e, intermediate facilities (nodes 17, 18 , 19).

Comment: i also provide original paper about that problem in drive folder.

Comment: Those nodes have `d[i] = 0` so your constraint says you cannot ship anything out of those nodes; is that what you want?

Comment: OK, but bear in mind that people on Stack Exchange are probably not willing to read a paper to help answer your question.

Comment: i want to d[i] for those node be updated when assigning customers to intermediate facilities happen (i.e when Z[i,j] = 1 for i in [17,18,19]), and be checked in cons04 if this assignment violate vehicle capacity (Q1) or not.

Comment: But `d[i]` is a parameter. You cannot change its value in a constraint.